# How does one obtain the pid of the currently debugged process in gdb?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

Inside gdb, what command will provide the pid of the process getting debugged?

Most of the [google results](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=gdb+get+the+pid+of+the+running+process&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=gdb+pid+of+the+currently+debugged+proccss) discuss only how to attach gdb to a process once we know the pid.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One simple way is `info inferior`.  Here I'm debugging gdb with itself and this command shows the PID of the debuggee:

```
(top-gdb) info inferior
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 1    process 14068     /home/tromey/gdb/build/gdb/gdb
```

You can also just call the ordinary C function:

```
(top-gdb) print getpid()
$3 = 14068
```

Comment: Note that the description will be `<null>` if the program is not being run. / Abbreviated as `i i`.

Comment: casting is required for getpid "print (int)getpid()"

Answer (score 4):

Another method:

```
(gdb) python print(gdb.selected_inferior().pid)
32737
```

See more info about the gdb Python inferior API:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-In-Python.html#Inferiors-In-Python

Answer (score 1):

On Linux `info proc` shows debugged process's pid and some other info

```
(gdb) info proc
process 28289
cmdline = '...'
cwd = '...'
exe = '...'
```

See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Information.html for detail